# How to have multiple implementation of UserDetaisService?

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-jpa, jwt

I have two categories of users from two different entities.

1. `AppUser`
2. `Restaurant`

Both of these have username and password, with each having it's other details. I also have separate login endpoints for both, so how can I now have the login logic using custom `UserDetaisService` implementation for both the categories.

The code for the `AppUser` is:

```java
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "appuser")
public class AppUser implements UserDetails {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(
            name = "appuser_sequence",
            sequenceName = "appuser_sequence",
            allocationSize = 1
    )
    @GeneratedValue(
            strategy = SEQUENCE,
            generator = "appuser_sequence"
    )
    private Long id;

    private String fullName;

    private String email;

    private String phoneNumber;

    private String password;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Role role;

    private Boolean locked;

    private Boolean enabled;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "appUser")
    private List<AppUserToken> appUserTokens;

    public AppUser(String fullName, String email, String phoneNumber, String password, Role role, Boolean locked, Boolean enabled) {
        this.fullName = fullName;
        this.email = email;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        this.password = password;
        this.role = role;
        this.locked = locked;
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return List.of(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.name()));
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return getEmail();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return !getLocked();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return getEnabled();
    }
}
```

And below is the code for `Restaurant`:

```java
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "restaurant")
public class Restaurant implements UserDetails {

  @Id
  @SequenceGenerator(
      name = "restaurant_sequence",
      sequenceName = "restaurant_sequence",
      allocationSize = 1
  )
  @GeneratedValue(
      strategy = SEQUENCE,
      generator = "restaurant_sequence"
  )
  private Long id;

  private String name;

  private String address;

  private String email;

  private String password;

  private String website;

  private Boolean registered;

  private Integer branch;

  private Long rangeFund;

  private String restaurantId;

  private Boolean locked;

  private Boolean enabled;

  private Role role;

  public Restaurant(String name, String address, String email, String password, String website, Boolean registered, Integer branch, Long rangeFund, String restaurantId, Boolean locked, Boolean enabled, Role role) {
    this.name = name;
    this.address = address;
    this.email = email;
    this.password = password;
    this.website = website;
    this.registered = registered;
    this.branch = branch;
    this.rangeFund = rangeFund;
    this.restaurantId = restaurantId;
    this.locked = locked;
    this.enabled = enabled;
    this.role = role;
  }

  @Override
  public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
    return List.of(new SimpleGrantesAuthority(role.name()));
  }

  @Override
  public String getPassword() {
    return password;
  }

  @Override
  public String getUsername() {
    return getEmail;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
    return !getLocked();
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isEnabled() {
    return getEnabled();
  }
}
```

And below is my `ApplicationConfig`:

```java
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ApplicationConfig {

  private final AppUserRepository appUserRepository;

  private final RestaurantRepository restaurantRepository;

  @Bean
  public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
    return new UserDetailsService() {

      @Override
      public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String loginUsername) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        final String type = loginUsername.substring(loginUsername.indexOf("_") + 1);
        final String username = loginUsername.substring(0, loginUsername.indexOf("_"));

        if (type.equals("USER")) {
          UserDetails appUser = appUserRepository.findUserByLoginUsername(username)
              .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("User with the username " + username + " Not Found"));

          return appUser;
        } else if (type.equals("RESTAURANT")) {
          UserDetails restaurant = restaurantRepository.findUserByLoginUsername(username)
              .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("User with the username " + username + " Not Found"));

          return restaurant;
        }

        throw new InvalidResourceException("Sorry invalid username");
      }
    };

//    return new UserDetailsService() {
//      @Override
//      public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String loginUsername) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
//        final String type = loginUsername.substring(loginUsername.indexOf("_") + 1);
//        final String username = loginUsername.substring(0, loginUsername.indexOf("_"));
////        AppUser appUser = appUserRepository.findUserByLoginUsername(username)
////            .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("User with the username " + username + " Not Found"));
////        return appUser;
//        Restaurant restaurant = restaurantRepository.findUserByLoginUsername(username).orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("User with the username " + username + " Not Found"));
//        return restaurant;
//      }
//    };
  }

  @Bean
  public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
    DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService());
    authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());

    return authProvider;
  }

  @Bean
  public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration config) throws Exception {
    return config.getAuthenticationManager();
  }

  @Bean
  public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
  }
}
```

And below is my `SecurityConfig`:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig {

  private final JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthFilter;

  private final AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

  private final LogoutHandler logoutHandler;

  @Bean
  public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeHttpRequests()
            .requestMatchers(
                "/api/v1/auth/user/**",
                "api/v1/auth/restaurant/**",
                "/v2/api-docs",
                "/v3/api-docs",
                "/v3/api-docs/**",
                "/swagger-resources",
                "/swagger-resources/**",
                "/configuration/ui",
                "/configuration/security",
                "/swagger-ui/**",
                "/webjars/**",
                "/swagger-ui.html"
            ).permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(STATELESS)
            .and()
        .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
        .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
        .logout()
            .addLogoutHandler(logoutHandler)
            .logoutUrl("/api/v1/auth/logout")
            .logoutSuccessHandler((request, response, authentication) -> SecurityContextHolder.clearContext()
        );

    return http.build();
  }
}
```

Below is `JwtAuthFilte`:

```java
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

  private final JwtService jwtService;

  private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

  private final AppUserTokenRepository appUserTokenRepository;

  @Override
  protected void doFilterInternal(@NonNull HttpServletRequest request, @NonNull HttpServletResponse response, @NonNull FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {

    final String authHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
    final String jwt;
    final String userEmail;

    if (authHeader == null || !authHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
      filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
      return;
    }

    jwt = authHeader.substring(7);

    userEmail = jwtService.extractUsername(jwt); // todo: extract user email from JWT token

    if (userEmail != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
      UserDetails userDetails = this.userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(userEmail);

      var isTokenValid = appUserTokenRepository.findByToken(jwt)
              .map(token ->
                !token.isExpired() && !token.isRevoked()
              ).orElse(false);

      if (jwtService.isTokenValid(jwt, userDetails) && isTokenValid) {
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());

        authToken.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));

        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authToken);
      }
    }

    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
  }
}
```

Comment: please state your reason for not using the built in JWT features that come with spring security stated in the spring security documentation jwt chapter? writing ccustom security is bad practice and whats the point of using a security framework if you dont intend to use it?